# Examples of situations where explaining the situation destabilizes the mind

Tags: logic, argumentation, consciousness

Could someone please provide, using logic, or some other reasoning or portrayal, an example of a situation where explaining the situation destabilizes the mind?

Thank you.

Comment: unsure how to use logic, but would suggest that explanations are stabalizing when you are confident that youi are being understood.

Comment: When you hear people claim something blows up their mind these are situations where explaining the situation destabilizes the mind, and perhaps it's very common when one really understands explanation which is contrary to one's prior core beliefs, as portrayed by the ancient Diamond Sutra: *The Buddha told Subhuti, “So it is, so it is. If someone hears this sutra and is not frightened, or alarmed, or terrified, you should know that person is most rare. And why? Subhuti, the foremost paramita is spoken of by the Tathagata as no foremost paramita, therefore it is called the foremost paramita...*

Comment: Could use more detail on what you mean by "destabilizes the mind"

Comment: “Anyone who is not shocked by quantum theory has not understood it.”
―Bohr. "If you think you understand quantum mechanics, you don't understand quantum mechanics." -Feynman

Comment: What of we could really understand how we think? We would AAARGH!

Comment: "Babe, it's not what it looks like"

Answer (score 1):

One famous example is from the Buddha's life. He had some followers that are called the Arhats or Arahants who were the most advanced students or practitioners. I am sure these people felt that they understood the teachings well. They had no doubts of their level of knowledge about it all.

So in one case the Buddha explained the idea of 'Emptiness' or *Shunyata*, and it so completely upended their views, that some fainted and it is said that some had heart attacks and died on the spot. This message is called the Heart Sutra, because it is the essential teaching, without which one understands basically nothing.

It is sometimes called the Heart *attack* Sutra, which is memorable but a bit disrespectful to the human situation. There is also something called "broken heart syndrome" where grief or other severe upset can emotionally cause physical issues, including death. Is this the kind of thing you were asking about?